# Filling dialog parameters from Django/Python app

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm creating a dashboard using Django that intends to simplify operation for several other (web) applications created by third parties, by redirecting the user to specific links on that applications without having to enter the information (customerId, user & passwd, etc) multiple times.

Flow is the following:

1. User logs in to a webpage (I've been able to store the cookie using urllib, and I could include it on the request to open the next page).
2. User clicks a "connect" button, that is opening a dialog using JQuery. Has to fill in several parameters and then clikc "OK" to submit the form.

I want to automate filling in the form and I'm completely lost.

- Do I have to use something like Selenium?
- How do I make the django web page open a new tab and fill in the parameters on that tab?

I can provide code but I don't exactly know what's required. I've been following the JS call flow and  have now located where the JQuery dialog is created and what requests are made at each point of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this with a bit of Javascript. I created a function "open_dt" which creates a new window, waits for it to load and then fill the parameters and click "OK".

Code looks like this:

```
function open_dt(param1, param1) {
    new_win = window.open("http://<my_url>/main");

    setTimeout("new_win.clickConnectButton()", 2000);
    setTimeout(function() { new_win.document.getElementById("form1_field").value = param1}, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() { new_win.document.getElementById("form2_field").value = param2}, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() { new_win.$("button > span:contains('OK')").click() }, 4000);

}
```

It's now working :) And, as the URL is on a different domain I had to disable Chrome's web security to allow cross domain.